# How to implement an interactive PDF in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf

Here im hitting my head againt the wall.

My client provided a pdf with buttons(just like buttons,when user tap on button,it will load next page and previous page etc.).

This buttons will work only when we open it in adobe reader.

I tried the QLpreviewview,quickview but it is not working,all what i can do is just to load the pdf in the webview.

Can anyone please help me in how to load an interactive pdf in iOS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a broad question.  However, to give you a little direction, I would start off by searching for available frameworks specializing in this.  Most, if not all, will cost, though. It wouldn't be exactly like adobe reader for obvious reasons, but they do offer similar interactions.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [PSPDFKit](http://pspdfkit.com), it is the most advanced framework I've found for PDFs in iOS. They have an impressive list of customers as well.

It is a bit pricy though, but you have the option to get the Source Code too if you need to modify anything. Could be worth it if your client need that kind of performance and other features as well.

(I am not in any way affiliated with PSPDFKit)

Comment: ,thanks for your suggestion.I tried PSPDF kit but didnt found the feature that i want in that.

Comment: Ok, shame. Hope you find what you're looking for somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

The limitations are due to the capabilities (or non-capabilities) of the PDF viewer used.

Currently the leading PDF viewer on iDevices is PDFExpert by Readdle. Adobe Reader for iDevices is weaker, but can deal to some extent with form elements.

For page navigation etc. you might use links instead of button fields (as far as you can live with the capabilities of links, and not use JavaScript). Links are said to be handled properly with many PDF viewers.

You may have to require certain PDF viewers on instructional level, because you don't have control over the viewer used by the actual user. And, as you noticed, many PDF viewers are simply too dumb do deal with active elements.

Another approach would be looking at PDF-to-HTML5 converters, and serve HTML5 from a server.